# Why does LocationListener have a constructor if it is an interface?

Tags: android, constructor, interface, locationlistener

I have seen that constructors aren't allowed within an interface, however how is this allowed?:

locationListener = new LocationListener() {
         etc }

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right interfaces can't have constructors but what you described is Anonymous Class. In this line you are creating object of new class without name that extends LocationListener (and implementation of it is between curly brackets).
If you want to get know some more about Anonymous Classes look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: thanks for the reply, but why does it require a constructor (LocationListener())?

Answer (score 1):

This is Anonymous class approach. To make it clear, here is an example.

```
interface Animal {
    public void cry();
}
```

To create an object of Animal instance, you need to implement the Animal interface first.

```
class Lion implements Animal {
    public void cry() {
        System.out.println("Roar");
    }
}
```

Then create an object using the usual approach:

```
Animal theLion = new Lion();
```

Another way is to create an Animal object using the Anonymous class.

```
Animal theTiger = new Animal() {
    public void cry() {
        System.out.println("Grrr");
    }
}
```

Now, both object should be able to call the `cry` method as:

```
theLion.cry();
theTiger.cry();
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the reply, but why does it require a constructor (Animal()) if there isn't a constructor defined in the interface?

Comment: because the Anonymous class is a shorthand for declaring a class like the Lion class.